# Embedding variable inside text using Trix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I would like to let users use variable name inside text box with Trix.

Given a trix text-box that let the user write messages to other user, I would like to be able to do something like this:
"Hello %user_name%"

When sending the message the user_name would be changed to whatever is the user_name.

I would except this to be a fairly standard feature but couldn't find mention of it in the documentation or SO.

I have tried doing a simple `.gsub` on the model.content.body but this is returning and `ActionText::RichText` who doesn't know what gsub is.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up not building the feature. Sorry not to be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to mock variables within text contents is to use search and replace, just replace the strings within the action that receives posted contents:

```
final_message = params[:message].gsub("%user_name%", "John Doe")
```

Note that gsub is only available for string type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have specified but the saved message is a template that will be sent to many users later on. Therefore I can not replace when receiving the message from the params.

I also tried a similar approach on the Trix object but it doesn't yield a string but a RichtText object.